# немогу удаленно подключиться к mysql (mariadb)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mariadb

Я поставил на виртуалку apache php mariadb, не хочу ставить phpmyadmin,
я обычно работаю через heidisql, но он что-то брыкается.
Для mysql я находил в конфиге строчку bind-address = 127.0.0.1 и комментировал ее, тут нет такой строки, хотя при конфиге вроде разрешил подключение и создал уже юзера со всеми привелегиями.
Адрес ip для подключения я узнал из ifconfig порт из netstat
Подскажите может что то где то забыл прописать??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну Вы же видите что Ваш mysql продолжил слушать только 127.0.0.1 . Вы убрали (закоментили) из конфига ключ `--skip-networking` как сказано в [мануале](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/)? Если и это не помогает, тогда замените `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` на `bind-address = 192.168.231.128` . Не забудьте после изменений конфига перезапускать mysqld. Так же может потребоваться разрешить коннекты в файрволле. Если у Вас firewalld - в статье по ссылке выше сказано как его править, если iptables, для теста можно просто сбросить все правила командой `iptables -F` предварительно сохранив куда-то вывод `iptables-save` .

Comment: да помогло, закомментировал bind-adress, нашел ее тут /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/